# How to open default calendar app from html email?

Tags: html, email, calendar, icalendar

I have in an html email a button. When clicked, this button should add an event in the user's default calender app on their computer. Here's my code:

```
<a href="webcal://domain.com/path/calendar.ics">
```

My question is: how to open the default app (not the web browser) of the user and add the event in their calendar using (or not using) an ics file. If an app can't be launched, then a maybe a popup window asking which app to use to open the file and add the event.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this for the default calendar app on a user's device. - Especially not through the email itself.

[Here](https://www.litmus.com/blog/how-to-create-an-add-to-calendar-link-for-your-emails/) is a resource that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to achieving this:

1. as Dr.Tenma says - on the user side, one cannot enforce how the user opens any file type.  What application is opened when a link to your url is clicked depends on their browser and/or mail and/or system settings.  For example: In firefox my settings say to open a.ics file in notepad++
2. The url/file itself must contain valid ics as per the RFC5545 specification, the mimetype in the header must be text/calendar.  I would also suggest using the official protocol of http/s.   Webcal is an unofficial apple protocol.  Many applications will cope with it if everything else is correct, but it is not the official protocol, not registered with IANA.